# Unhandled Exception in Recycler view xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

When I am clicking `recyclerview`, App has stoped and showing error message

> Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.LinkageError: no method with
>   name='getContext' signature='()Landroid/content/Context;' in class
>   Landroid/app/Fragment;"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI4sD.png)
...

Do you know how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Activity that is hosting the Fragment as your context:

```
var context = fragment.Activity;
```

So your LinearLayoutManager .ctor would be:

```
... = new LinearLayoutManager(this.Activity, ....
```

Note: Do **not** use images for code, add the formatted text directly to your question.

Comment: Thanks You,I use Activity.It can Solve the problem:D